# Don't show object in RecyclerView that came from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I get a list of events from Firebase and use FirebaseUI to populate a RecyclerView. An event object has a field called attended that is either true or false.

How can I hide/remove objects that have a value of false in the field attended? I know the best way to do it would be to store all attended events separately and then populate the RecyclerView from that, but due to the structure of the event, this is not possible.

**Edit:**

```
    2019-04-02 12:32:51.126 7807-7807/com.example.concertmate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.concertmate, PID: 7807
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using orderByPriority(), values provided to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() must be valid priorities.
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.validateQueryEndpoints(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:106)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:377)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:363)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.equalTo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:568)
        at com.example.concertmate.Fragments.ConcertFragment.onCreateView(ConcertFragment.java:115)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
2019-04-02 12:32:51.126 7807-7807/com.example.concertmate E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:717)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2917)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1747)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2040)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7795)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1172)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-04-02 12:32:51.127 7807-7807/com.example.concertmate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.concertmate, PID: 7807
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using orderByPriority(), values provided to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() must be valid priorities.
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.validateQueryEndpoints(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:106)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:377)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:363)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.equalTo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:568)
        at com.example.concertmate.Fragments.ConcertFragment.onCreateView(ConcertFragment.java:115)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
2019-04-02 12:32:51.127 7807-7807/com.example.concertmate E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:717)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2917)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1747)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2040)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7795)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1172)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the error I get when I try to use equalTo for the query.

```
 query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("concert").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).equalTo(true,"favorite");
```

And here is the image of the database structure.
[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITRi.png)

It's `concert -> user uuid -> event uuid`.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside onBind in your recyclerView view you can check that variable if it's true or false. If it's true you can move to the next object and no set values.

It would helpful if you provided some examples what have you tried and how your recyclerView is setup so that i can actually give some working examples.

Another option is to query data in a way that will retrieve only objects that are true or only the ones that false.

Comment: I tried doing it by query " query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .child("concert").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).equalTo(true,"favorite") " but it doesn't work. i get an error. I tried using setVisibility(gone) on the holder but that hides it yet the card is still taking up space.  How would i be able to move to the next object in the onBind method though ?